# Finding start and end date from given year and month in Unix

Tags: date, unix

I have a unix script named `myScript` where two arguments should be passed in `YYYYMM` format indicating starting month and ending month for the script.

Inside the script, based on the argument, I need to calculate the start date of the month in first argument and the end date of the month in second argument.

I wrote the below code:

```
startYr=`expr substr $2 1 4`
startMonth=`expr substr $2 5 2`
startDate=`cal $startMonth $startYr | grep . | fmt -1 | tail -1`

endYr=`expr substr $3 1 4`
endMonth=`expr substr $3 5 2`
endDate=`cal $endMonth $endYr | grep . | fmt -1 | tail -1`

export eomStartDate=$startYr-$startMonth-$startDate
export eomEndDate=$endYr-$endMonth-$endDate

echo "START DATE: $eomStartDate"
echo "END DATE: $eomEndDate"
```

However, on running above script as:

```
myScript 201401 201412
```

The result I am getting is:

```
START DATE: 2014-12-31
END DATE: --31
```

What am I missing ? I am using Korn Shell.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters should be $1 and $2, not $2 and $3. Also, for start date you should do `sed -n 10p` to get the 10th line, from where the days start.